# Implementing JWT expiry use case

Tags: authentication, jwt

Consider the following:

User A obtained a JWT token to use for authentication. It has an expiry time of 30 minutes. When User A makes a request, a middleware checks the time created vs the current time to see if it has expired. If it expired, the old token is deleted and User A is given a new token.

User B, who stole the JWT token from User A with a way or another, before expiry (this use case focuses on damage control and not on how to protect JWT from theft). User B entered his browser in the same domain (considering we blocked requests from another domains) and entered the token in his browser. On expiry, the middleware will think that User A is sending the request and will grant User B a new token. In this case, User A will now be unauthenticated, until he relogins, and User B can now send requests as much as he wants.

Is there a way of dealing with this problem, or is my logic wrong?

Comment: This article from Auth0 may be of interest to you, regarding "refresh tokens" in an authentication scheme: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: In general, if an active JWT gets stolen you cannot do anything about it. The only way of adding some security is CORS but that seems like something you’ve set already. In your scenario both users would get exchange tokens, especially if both users query from the same IP.